# Does WinUI support MVVM?

Tags: mvvm, winui-3

Clicking on a ListViewItem and having it execute some action in a view model is the most basic command, but I can't find any bindable properties on the ListView or ListViewItem. Maui, at least, has gesture behaviors. This is how it should work:

```
    <ListView DataContext="{x:Bind ViewModel.FolderViewModel}"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}"
              Tapped={x:Bind Tapped}">
    </ListView>
```

Please, what am I missing. Is there another, more clever, native way to do this? If so, what is it. If not, why is MVVM not supported?

Yes, I know there are external packages. I feel like I just got into a new automobile, and there was no steering wheel. If steering is such an important concept for driving, then where is the steering wheel? If the car's manufacturer has invented an auto-driving car, then I need learn this new paradigm. If the manufacturer just says "Go buy a steering wheel at AutoZone", then it's just a crappy design.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the MVVM design.

There are some controls like `Button`s that let you bind the `Command` directly but for `ListView`s, you need to convert the `event` to a `Command`. This is almost the same in **WPF**, **UWP**.

**NuGet packages**

- CommunityToolkit.Mvvm
- Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.WinUI.Managed

**.xaml**

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="WinUI3App1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel>
        <ListView>
            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectItemCommand}" />
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <ListViewItem Content="Item #1" />
            <ListViewItem Content="Item #2" />
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

**.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
namespace WinUI3App1;

public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new();
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
namespace WinUI3App1;

public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [RelayCommand]
    private void SelectItem(object param)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I understand that there are many, many different ways to program around this using outside packages. I've written some myself and it's as ugly as this code. This should be one line. One bindable attribute set to the command handler. Where are the core functions in WinUI that support MVVM directly?

Comment: Actually, the **CommunityToolkit.Mvvm** package is reducing a bunch of boilerplate code using source-generators. IMHO, this is an awesome package. You can see yourself in [this](https://youtu.be/aCxl0z04BN8) tutorial form James Montemagno.